# Cell incrementation after for loop with Vlookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help on looping with `FormulaR1C1` when using `Vlookup`.

I had been looking for threads related to what I needed but no help was found. I am trying to increase the lookup value cell after each loop but there is always defined error.

- I need the "VALUE" to increment by 2 each time it loop pass the code.
- The problem is that the VBA does not accept the statement, do I have any ways other than using R1C1?

*Example code*

```
g=100
VALUE= 5
Worksheets.("NewData").Select
For i = 1 To 7
Worksheets.("NewData").Cells( g + i, 4).FormulaR1C1= "=Vlookup(R[-VALUE]C[+1], Data!R1C1:R100C100, 2, False)"
VALUE=VALUE+2
Next i
```

Comment: Could you add an example of your input spreadsheet and your expected output?

Comment: Edit 1: Below is the how the code should do for me
-Lookup value at column FUNCTION TEXT 2
(http://i60.tinypic.com/2im16wy.png)
-Lookup table
(http://i61.tinypic.com/240x552.png)
-Output of Vlookup cell starting from R148C2
(http://i61.tinypic.com/16kb76g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the VALUE data into the formula:

```
g=100
VALUE= 5
Worksheets.("NewData").Select
For i = 1 To 7
Worksheets.("NewData").Cells( g + i, 4).FormulaR1C1= "=Vlookup(R[-" & VALUE & "]C[+1], Data!R1C1:R100C100, 2, False)"
VALUE=VALUE+2
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, man! That was a brilliant answer. It works amazingly. Thanks again!